remove target from service control policies using IAM policy
There is a requirement that I need to remove the QA account as a target from the management account service control policy, do some activity, and then attach the QA account back to the service control policy. I have created the following policy and attached it to an EC2 instance role (in the QA account).
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "organizations:DetachPolicy",
                "organizations:AttachPolicy",
                "organizations:DescribePolicy",
                "organizations:ListPolicies"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:organizations::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:policy/o-c8bmqs41m1/service_control_policy/p-f4xeygjf"
        }
    ]
}
 

Now, when I take ssh of the ec2 instance and run list-policies command , I am getting permission issue.
#aws organizations list-policies --filter SERVICE_CONTROL_POLICY

An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the ListPolicies operation: You don't have permissions to access this resource.

AM i missing anything ?

Is your Instance Role from the Organization management account, or from some other account in the Organization?  Only the management account can modify Organization configuration.

This is fixed by delegating the resource-based access policy, which needs to be defined in the management account by navigating to Organizations -> Settings -> Delegated Administrator for AWS Organizations.
